# PyRO 4 - lookup fails when I try to find a registered object

Tags: macos, python-3.x, lookup, pyro

I'm fighting against this problem for about a week, and I don't know anymore where to look to find a solution.

As the title says, as soon as I successfully register a pyro object, I try to find it on the NS, in order to operate with it, but the lookup fails.

I post a simplified version of my code, to make the situation more clear:

Server is the class in which the PyRO NS starts:

```
import threading, socket, sys
import Pyro4


class Server():

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_ns_loop()

    def start_ns(self):

        print("Starting the Name Server...")

        try:

            Pyro4.naming.startNSloop()

        except socket.error:

            print("Name Server already running.")
            sys.exit(0)

    def start_ns_loop(self):

        ns_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_ns, args=[])
        ns_thread.daemon = True
        ns_thread.start()
```

TextAnalyzer class is the class that I use to do some statistics about a file:

```
    import nltk, argparse, Pyro4, socket
    class TextAnalyzer():


    def __init__(self):
        #init function in which I do all my things...

    '''after the init, I've some methods. I don't list them
    because they are not important in this discussion'''

    def get_ip_addr(self):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        ns_ip = str(s.getsockname()[0])
        s.close()

        return ns_ip


def main():

    global nsip, PYRO_OBJ_NAME
    text_analyzer_name = "Text_Analyzer_"

    # Parser configuration for the input values
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Values: ")
    parser.add_argument("-id", help="Sets the text analyzer ip.")
    parser.add_argument("-nsip", help="Sets the Name Server ip.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.id is not None:
        identifier = str(args.id)
    else:
        identifier = ""

    if args.nsip is not None:
        name_server_ip = str(args.nsip)
    else:
        name_server_ip = ""

    a = TextAnalyzer()

    try:

        if name_server_ip != "":
            nsip = Pyro4.naming.locateNS(name_server_ip)
        else:
            nsip = Pyro4.naming.locateNS()

        PYRO_OBJ_NAME = text_analyzer_name + str(identifier)
        print("PyRO Object name: " + PYRO_OBJ_NAME)
        daemon = Pyro4.Daemon(a.get_ip_addr())

        uri_text_analyzer = daemon.register(a)
        nsip.register(PYRO_OBJ_NAME, uri_text_analyzer, safe=True)

        print("URI " + PYRO_OBJ_NAME + ": " + str(uri_text_analyzer))

        daemon.requestLoop()

    except Pyro4.naming.NamingError as e:

        print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Connection class provides all methods useful to find the object on the NS, sftp and ssh connection, finds the PID of the objects running, etc...

```
import Pyro4, paramiko, socket, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Connection(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):

    super(Connection, self).__init__()

    self.text_analyzer_name = "Text_Analyzer_"
    self.identifier = None
    self.address = None
    self.password = None
    self.object_pid = None
    self.authentication_ok = False

def get_ip_addr(self):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ns_ip = str(s.getsockname()[0])
    s.close()
    print(ns_ip)
    return ns_ip

# This method finds the object on the NS
def find_obj(self, identifier, a, p):

    self.identifier = identifier
    self.address = a
    self.password = p

    self.open_server_connection()

    time.sleep(5)

    if self.authentication_ok is True:

        try:
            ns = Pyro4.naming.locateNS()
            print("Return del locateNS(): " + str(ns))
            uri_text_analyzer = ns.lookup(self.text_analyzer_name + str(self.identifier))
            self.text_analyzer = Pyro4.Proxy(uri_text_analyzer)
            return True

        except Pyro4.errors.NamingError as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.ssh_connection_close_and_cleanup()
            return False

def open_server_connection(self):

    print("Object ID: " + str(self.identifier))

    ssh_connection = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh_connection.load_system_host_keys()

    ssh_connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

    try:
        if str(self.address).__contains__('@'):
            (username, hostname) = self.address.split('@')
            print("User: " + username + ", Host: " + hostname)
            print("Tento la connessione.")
            ssh_connection.connect(str(hostname), username=username, password=str(self.password), timeout=5, allow_agent=False)

        else:
            ssh_connection.connect(str(self.address), password=str(self.password), timeout=5, allow_agent=False)

        self.authentication_ok = True

        ns_ip = self.get_ip_addr()
        sftp_connection = ssh_connection.open_sftp()
        print("Sftp connection open.")
        print("Transferring " + self.text_analyzer_name + str(self.identifier) + "...")
        sftp_connection.put("text_analyzer.py", "./text_analyzer.py")
        print("Transferring Pyro4...")
        sftp_connection.put("Pyro4.zip", "./Pyro4.zip")
        print("Unpacking...")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_connection.exec_command("tar -xzvf Pyro4.zip")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Executing " + self.text_analyzer_name + str(self.identifier) + ":")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_connection.exec_command("echo $$; exec python3 text_analyzer.py -id {} -nsip {}".format(self.identifier, ns_ip))

        # Object PID saving
        self.object_pid = int(stdout.readline())
        print("PID del " + self.text_analyzer_name + str(self.identifier) + ": " + str(self.object_pid))
        # Connections close
        ssh_connection.close()
        sftp_connection.close()

    except (paramiko.AuthenticationException, socket.error) as e:
        self.authentication_ok = False
        ssh_connection.close()
        print("Connection failed, error: " + str(e))

def ssh_connection_close_and_cleanup(self):

    ssh_connection = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh_connection.load_system_host_keys()

    ssh_connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

    try:
        if str(self.address).__contains__('@'):
            (username, hostname) = self.address.split('@')
            ssh_connection.connect(str(hostname), username=username, password=str(self.password), timeout=5, allow_agent=False)
        else:
            ssh_connection.connect(str(self.address), password=str(self.password), timeout=5, allow_agent=False)

        self.host = hostname
        print("Killing PID: " + str(self.object_pid))
        ssh_connection.exec_command("/bin/kill -KILL {}".format(self.object_pid))
        ssh_connection.exec_command("rm -r Pyro4")
        ssh_connection.exec_command("rm -r Pyro4.zip")
        ssh_connection.exec_command("rm text_analyzer.py")
        time.sleep(5)

        ssh_connection.close()

    except(paramiko.AuthenticationException, socket.error) as e:
        ssh_connection.close()
        print("Connection failed")
        print(str(e))
```

So, basically, this is what I'm doing.

The problem is that the lookup fails while trying to find the remote object on the NS, inside the find_obj() method (contained within Connection class), but I know for sure that the remote object was registered successfully.

The error given is "unknown name" from Pyro4.errors.NamingError.

I have really no clue why it isn't working...

Further specs: I'm running it on Mac OS X Mavericks, with PyRO 4 and Python 3.4.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nsc tool to look in the name server's database. Make sure you connect to the correct name server. You will see that the object you request is really not in there. (Otherwise Pyro will hand you the uri).

Another tip might be to check that the name you're requesting is exactly the same as what you registered with. Also check if you have multiple name servers running perhaps, and is your code getting them mixed up maybe?